# Mysql GROUP BY with MAX(DATE) and MIN (DATE)

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max, min

in my mysql table, I have a date column and a ticket column:

```
+------------+------------+
| Ticket     | Date       |
+------------+------------+
| 1          | 2020-02-02 |
| 1          | 2020-03-03 |
| 1          | 2020-04-02 |
| 2          | 2020-04-05 |
| 2          | 2020-04-09 |
| 2          | 2020-04-15 |
+------------+------------+
```

How can I select with one query min(DATE) and max(DATE) for each ticket, the result should be:

```
+------------+------------+------------+
| Ticket     | MIN Date   | MAX DATE   |
+------------+------------+------------+
| 1          | 2020-02-02 | 2020-04-02 |
| 2          | 2020-04-05 | 2020-04-15 |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

That's simple aggregation:

```
select ticket, min(date) mindate, max(date) maxdate
from mytable
group by ticket
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select ticket, date
from table name
where (ticket in (select max(date)
                  from table name)
       UNION
       ticket = (select min(date)
                 from table name))
```